# Mac Book Air M1 2020 - Display Link is asking randomly for screen recording permissions when device is locked

Tags: permission, dock, screen-capture

I have connected my Mac Book Air M1 2020 to a PRIPC1 IPC-Computer USB-C / USB 3.0 Docking Station with Display Link to connect my to external displays. So far it worked pretty well. I went into the settings and allowed Display Link to use screen recording permissions.

But when I lock my screen and go away for some while, it sometimes happens, that the Display Link software crashes and asking me for screen recording permissions again, however they are already in place. I then have to open my Mac Book Air, unplug it from the docking station and turn the screen recording settings on and off again. Then it worked like nothing happend.

Here a screenshot of the notification, when the crash happens:

[image: PRIPC1 IPC-Computer USB-C / USB 3.0 Docking Station]

Screen Recording permissions:
[image]

Display Link Settings (Login Screen Extension installed):
[image]

I hope you could help me with this. Google does not provide any help until now.

Comment: Did you update the displaylink software to the latest version? Or can you use an older version that didn't have this behaviour? I know they regularly roll out updates that fix/introduce these kind of bugs.

Comment: Hi Saaru, according to the display Link website, I have the newest version installed. Older versions are compatible with Mac OS Catalina. I have Big Sur installed.

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to mention, that I was able to fix the error by reinstalling an older version 1.5.0 of Display Link Manager. Now it works also without any troubles with my docking station.